# How to efficiently generate a table with a large number of rows using iText 7

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext, itext7

I am trying to generate a PDF document using iText 7 core library. The problem I currently have is that it is really slow and for the number of entries I have tested with (3000 rows where one row is composed of 12 columns. The actual needed number later will be much higher) takes around 3 minutes.

Below I give you what I have already tried and the methods that actually give me the slow writing results.

```
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        LoadLicense();

        listOfValues = GetListOfValues(values);

        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetPath));
        var document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4);

        var table = new Table(new[] { 10f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f });
        table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        // HeaderTitlesList is just an array of strings
        foreach (var title in HeaderTitlesList)
        {
            WriteHeader(table, title);
        }

        for (var row = 0; row < measurement.MeasurementPoints.Count; row++)
        {
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].main}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].first}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].second}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].third}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].fifth:0.###}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].sixth}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].seventh:0.###}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].eighth}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].nineth}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].tenth:0.###}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].main:0}");
            WriteRow(table, $"{listOfValues[row].main:0.##}");
        }
        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();

    }, cancellationToken);
    return true;
}


private static void WriteRow(Table table, string cellVal)
{
    table.AddCell(cellVal).SetBorder(new SolidBorder(new DeviceRgb(0, 0, 0), 0.5f));
}

private static void WriteHeader(Table table, string title)
{
    var cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(title));
    cell.SetFont(PdfFont)
        .SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(0, 74, 136))
        .SetFontColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 255, 255))
        .SetPadding(5)
        .SetBorder(CellBorder);
    table.AddHeaderCell(cell);
}
```

Is there a way to perhaps instead of writing all these values cell by cell generate them row by row? Anything that would make the PDF generating process at least a tad quicker is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have just tried to use the iText suggested method from a post [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/large-tables) and tried a rather small, in our case, use case where around 40 000 cells had to be written. This already takes over a minute.

```
protected void manipulatePdf(string dest)
        {
            var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
            var doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

            var table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(12), true);

            foreach (var cellVal in HeaderTitlesList)
            {
                table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().SetKeepTogether(true).Add(new Paragraph(cellVal)));
            }

            doc.Add(table);
            for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
            {
                if (i % 12 == 0)
                {
                    table.Flush();
                }
                table.AddCell(new Cell().SetKeepTogether(true).Add(new Paragraph("Test " + i).SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)));
            }

            table.Complete();

            doc.Close();
        }
```

This leads me to think that this library is just not "quick" enough for our use case.

Comment: `Table` implements `ILargeElement`. You should consider making use of that.

Comment: @mkl can you give more info on this?

Comment: *"can you give more info on this?"* - Unfortunately not beyond your EDIT. I merely would not flush after each row but instead after 10 or 20 rows. But I assume that won't make a big difference.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code in `Release` mode in .NET? It takes 9-10 seconds on my laptop to add the 40K cells from your edit. Looks like a reasonable result if you take into account that the resultant document is 176 pages.

Comment: @AlexeySubach, guess it depends a lot on a device the code is run from. My numbers come from Xamarin application and a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5.

Comment: @PaulinhoInso where you able to come with a solution for this? ?I am having slowness after migrating from itextsharp to itext7?

Comment: @PaulinhoInso did you figure this out? it takes 1 minute to load 500 page table and is so unacceptable.